# Navigating through multiple child views contained in Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a an WPF MVVM application where I need to have a Main Window with just a logo and it has to show child views inside it. I don't have any controls in Main Window all the controls reside in child view for example Buttons like Next, Back, Cancel and some text blocks etc. Now If users select Next button on the child view I have to draw or load the next child view inside the Main Window. If Back button is clicked I have to go back to the previous child view. So basically I am changing the child views depending on which button is clicked. Also I am maintaining different view models for every child view. Now the problem is I am not able to figure how should I link the child views to there respective view models. This application is similar to some Installation applications where different dialogs are shown depending on the selection and the button clicked by the user.I am new to this wpf and don't want to use MVVM Light , Prism etc. Any detailed help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prism has extensive code dedicated to navigation, and maintaining a view history. Why don't you want to use an existing framework that does this already?

Comment: @Mashton thank you for the suggestion :) actually I am new to this wpf and do not want to confuse myself with these different kinds. In future I should definitely go for Prism and other similar stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to associate any data type with XAML controls is to use a `DataTemplate`. Therefore, you can simply add something like this into your `Application.Resources` and as long as you *do not set the `x:Key` properties on the `DataTemplate`s*, then they will be explicitly applied by the Framework whenever it comes across instances of your view models:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HomeViewModel}">
    <Views:HomeView />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then displaying the view is as simple as this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourViewModelProperty"} />
```

In code behind, or your view model:

```
YourViewModelProperty = new MainViewModel();
```

It's often handy to create a base class for your view models and then the `YourViewModelProperty` can of that type and you will be able to interchange them using the same property and `ContentControl`.

---

UPDATE >>>

The general idea is that you have one `MainViewModel` class with one `BaseViewModel` property data bound to one `ContentControl` in `MainWindow.xaml`... the navigation controls should also be in `MainWindow.xaml` and not in the views themselves. In this way, the `MainViewModel` class is responsible for changing the property to the relevant view model instances when it receives navigation `Command`s from the `MainWindow.xaml`.

Comment: Never thought about binding to a ViewModel type and using a template for the views. Very clever, +1!

Comment: @Sheridan thanks for the answer.I have a doubt here where do I need to have the YourViewModelProperty. Do I need to have an application wide View Model which exposes this property. If yes how am I able to change this property when switching from one view to another on button click event of the first view. I can understand that wpf is going to draw the view on the main window depending on the content present in YourViewModelProperty. but suppose if I am done with first view and wants to show the next view to user how shall I do that?

Comment: how to get an instance of HomeViewModel into HomeView this way?

Comment: What do you mean *how to*? This *is* how to.