# Hide/Show user control, or dispose user control better approach

Tags: wpf, winforms, mvvm

I have a WPF  Winform application. The form has a header on the top and a user control below. Once i am done entering values in the user control, i want to dismiss this user control and add another user control in that area. I will have 4 user controls in a sequence and I may have to move back to the previous user control or move forward.

Which is the better approach to achieve this in MVVM? To hide and view the user controls or dispose the user control.

Comment: I think it's a view design issue. The ViewModel is not supposed to know anything about how the view is layed out. Wether to hide or dispose. Since you can go back to the control my first option would be to hide, unless these controls take up a huge amount of resources (memory and so)

Comment: Please see my answer to the [Navigating through multiple child views contained in Main Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137371/navigating-through-multiple-child-views-contained-in-main-window/23137536#23137536) question for an example of the usual way to do this in MVVM applications.

Answer (score 0):

Hide. Its simpler.

Also your description sounds remarkably like a wizard, so you might want to look at using a [NavigationFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as this would then allow you to "navigate" to the next set of controls once once set is complete.

P.S. Navigation frames can very easily be styled to completely remove the navigation bar UI, see http://winchrome.codeplex.com/ for some examples

Comment: -1 Hiding is a terrible idea unless the views are tiny. If you have all of your views initialised at once (even if they are hidden), they are taking up resources, eg. RAM. WPF is resource-hungry enough as it is without wasting further resources in this way.

Comment: +1 I removed my down vote because you have provided an alternative solution.

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear, but from the question it looked like the views were tiny